# Wp ajax not working from "current_screen" admin hook

Tags: admin, ajax, oop

I have a class that is doing some backend work ( enqueening css and js files creating metaboxes, registering ajax hooks etc...)

Everything works fine when I just include the files. 
The problem is that the files are included on every admin page.

In order to include them only on the page I really want ( CPT ) I've used the ['current_screen'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/current_screen) admin hook.

Inside that hook it's safe to use ['get_current_screen' function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)

I use that function to determine on what page I'm currently on, so I can add appropriate classes.
What happens next is that my class continues to work as expected ( enqueening css, js, creating metaboxes) only on CPT page, but ajax hooks stop working (response 0).

Ajax requests get triggered by clicking on the buttons inside the metaboxes.

I'm not really sure what's going on, there are no php errors.

1. works:

   ```
    include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'/src/MyClass.php');

    new MyClass();
   ```
2. broken:

   ```
   add_action('current_screen',"iki_admin_current_screen");

   function iki_admin_current_screen()
   {

      $screen = get_current_screen();

      if($screen->id == 'portfolio')
      {
         include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'/src/MyClass.pnp;
         new MyClass();
      }

   }
   ```
3. broken:

   ```
   include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'/src/MyClass.
   add_action('current_screen',"iki_admin_current_screen");

   function iki_admin_current_screen()
   {

      $screen = get_current_screen();

      if($screen->id == 'portfolio')
      {
         new MyClass();
      }

   }
   ```

I would like to point out that the class works in all three examples, except for the AJAX calls, which work only on the first example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current screen in the context of an AJAX request, only in the context of where you're making the AJAX calls *from*.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more?
What is Ajax Context?

I'm only creating the class via that hook.
Ajax call is bound to the public method of the class.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: The request for the portfolio admin page is entirely separate from the AJAX request you make *from* that page- two different, unrelated http requests. When the AJAX request is sent to the server, it doesn't pass your current screen test because it's not a request for the portfolio admin page, it's an AJAX request. add your AJAX handlers outside your current screen action.

Comment: I think we don't understand each other correctly, `current_screen` hook is only used to determine on what page to include and instantiate the php class.That hook is fired after the `admin_init` hook.

 I'm not making multiple requests. Ajax request is sent when the user clicks on the button inside the metabox.

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but you're not understanding my explanation. when someone clicks the button in your meta box, that's another request being sent to the server. when that request is processed by the server, your class is not present because your current screen action is not firing on that request, so your AJAX handlers don't exist. This is not unique to WordPress, this is how AJAX works. think of it like opening a separate browser window and opening a different page- one window is not "aware" of the state of the other window, they're two entirely separate requests.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you are saying. 
How would you solve this problem?
Maybe include and instantiate the class outside the `current_screen` action, and create something like `init`method on the class, and trigger that method inside the action? `init` method would then enqueue necessary scripts, create metaboxes register ajax callbacks etc..?

Comment: instantiate it on every request and check the context within each part separately- when you enqueue scripts, when you add meta boxes. you can also check if a request is AJAX via `if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)`

Comment: Yeah, I think that will do it, however, I've thought that there would be a easier way, so I could just check once on what page I'm currently on, and if it's the one that I want, I just instantiate the class and enqueue all the assets I need. 
So practically, the solution is to include and instantiate the class on every page load, and to check on what page I'm on only when it's time to do the appropriate action ( inside the `admin_enqueue_scripts` etc..)